# Mongodb ReplicaSet

Tags: mongodb

You have just been hired at a new company with an existing MongoDB deployment. They are running a single replica set with two members. When you ask why, they explain that this ensures that the data will be durable in the face of the failure of either server. They also explain that should they use a readPreference of "primaryPreferred", that the application can read from the one remaining server during server maintenance.

You are concerned about two things, however. First, a server is brought down for maintenance once a month. When this is done, the replica set primary steps down, and the set cannot accept writes. You would like to ensure availability of writes during server maintenance.

Second, you also want to ensure that all writes can be replicated during server maintenance.

Which of the following options will allow you to ensure that a primary is available during server maintenance, and that any writes it receives will replicate during this time?

Check all that apply.

1. Add two arbiters.
2. Add another data bearing node.
3. Add two data bearing members plus one arbiter.
4. Add an arbiter.
5. Increase the priority of the first server from one to two.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a copy/paste of a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This question regarding the majority and replication.
A parameter of the majority is minimum equal - 2/3. The replication this is a possibility to replicate data between at least two servers. 
So, we have here the following picture:

1. Add two arbiters.  (majority 3/4)
2. Add another data bearing node. (majority 2/3)
3. Add two data bearing members plus one arbiter. (majority 4/5)
4. Add an arbiter. (majority 2/3)
5. Increase the priority of the first server from one to two.(nothing for majority)

Now, you have to figure out the correct majority and think about which of the remaining variants will cover the replication.